# MPI Unexpected output

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, ubuntu-10.04

I was reading and practicing MPI programs from a tutorial. There I saw an example of finding a rank of a process. But the same example is giving different output on my machine(Ubuntu 10.04)..
Here is the program

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <mpi.h> 
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int ierr, num_procs, my_id;

  ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  /* find out MY process ID, and how many processes were started. */

  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_id);
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs);

  printf("Hello world! I'm process %i out of %i processes\n", 
     my_id, num_procs);

  ierr = MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The expected output according to the tutorial is

Expected Output :

```
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 4 processes.
Hello world! I'm process 2 out of 4 processes.
Hello world! I'm process 1 out of 4 processes.
Hello world! I'm process 3 out of 4 processes.
```

Output which I am getting

```
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 1 processes
```

My machine uses intel i3,Dell Inspiron and is having Ubuntu 10.04 OS.Help me resolving the problem.

Comment: What command do you use to run your application? MPI applications are typically ran using `mpirun` or similar tools.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPI\_Rank return same process number for all process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287564/mpi-rank-return-same-process-number-for-all-process)

Answer (score 0):

I have just compiled and run your program on my Ubuntu:

```
tom@tom-ThinkPad-T500:~/MPI_projects/Start/net2/net2/bin/Debug$ mpirun -n 6 ./output
Hello world! I'm process 3 out of 6 processes
Hello world! I'm process 4 out of 6 processes
Hello world! I'm process 0 out of 6 processes
Hello world! I'm process 2 out of 6 processes
Hello world! I'm process 1 out of 6 processes
Hello world! I'm process 5 out of 6 processes
```

Enter the folder with your executable file and run:

`mpirun -np 2 ./output`

or

`mpirun -np 6 ./output`

the flag -np modifies the number of called processes (http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun).

You can also run `mpirun` without any flags to display lots of useful info.

Another interesting command is `mpirun -info`, which will show print MPI build information.

This is the first part of my output:

```
tom@tom-ThinkPad-T500:~/MPI_projects/Start/net2/net2/bin/Debug$ mpirun -info
HYDRA build details:
Version:                                 1.4.1
Release Date:                            Wed Aug 24 14:40:04 CDT 2011
```

The last resort is to re-install or update your MPI using, for example, the following command : `sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc`